# Fault Finding SSIS "Unexpected Termination" - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I have been getting an "Unexpected Termination" error from time to time on a bunch of SSIS jobs that I am running on a SQL Server 2016 instance (Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-CU2) (KB3182270) - 13.0.2164.0 (X64)).  The server is a virtual server, running Windows Server 2012 R2, 4 processors and 52gb of ram.

I have a Master package/sub package project that is running around 200 packages in parallel. I have the Project set to run the default number of parallel processes, being 6.

The failures, when they do occur, appear to be pretty consistent.  Basically,   what is happening is the first 6 sub packages kick off.  It appears to me that when it goes to pick up the next package the termination occurs.

I have checked the logs and I can't see anything written that is abnormal - there are no on warning or on error messages that are any different to if the packages run to completion.  I can't see any other abnormal events in the servers event logs.

Does anyone have any clues on what may be happening, or any tips on how to fault find this issue?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3136619/ssis-2016-packages-abort-with-unexpected-termination-message). I suggest you apply SP1 and latest CU. I do not have any evidence that this will fix your issue but based on the bug in 2012, mentioned in the connect item.

Comment: Some troubleshooting tips [here](https://devjef.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/ssisdb-why-bigger-isnt-always-better/).

Comment: Thanks @SqlWorldWide.  I had looked at the info from the 2012 release and had discounted it, figuring that the issue was well and truly fixed.  Regardless, I'll look at applying SP1 and see if that works.  As for the size and logging from your other suggestion, I'm at 9GB, so not THAT big.  I'll need to further analyze that and see how it fits.  Cheers

Comment: I've just upgraded to 2016 SP1 CU4 and no difference.  Back to the drawing board I suppose (I will look at the other tips first).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I am going to sound like the worse developer in the world, but the issue went away.....  So, no I didn't find a fix for it.

Comment: This started happening in our prod environment. Our log is 72GB but the SSIS server maintenance job takes only 1 min, and the server doesn't seem to be struggling with anything at all, any suggestion on how to track down the root cause ?